# Bandwidth throttling for Files in C#

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, throttling

I have an application that upload a file to S3 Amazon which internally uses ThrottledStream class to control the bandwidth. I want to give the user the provision to adjust bandwidth as per the percentage between 0-100%, as client will not understand byte transfer rate. 
Throlled stream takes input parameter as FileStream/Stream and bps (byte/bit per second). How can i adjust the bps value based on the percentage set by user?
I have limited knowledge of throttling, your suggestions will really help me.

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  100% of _what_?

Comment: You'd have to know the minimum and maximum bps to do the conversion. Do you know that?

Comment: I dont know the min and max bps, should i calculate it based on the current bandwidth speed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to have to pick a maximum value, such as 100kbs then set the rate based on the percentage.

```
long bps = (long)(102400 * ((double)percent / 100.0);   
if (percent == 100)
   bps = ThrottledStream.Infinite;
ts = new ThrottledStream(originalDestinationStream, bps);
```

I haven't compiled it, but I would guess something like that.